# Questions on Firebase Cloud Messages topics vs groups

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I made two databases in my project.

db1 contains a collection of unique tokens for each device that's currently wishing to receive notifications in my application.

db2 contains entities which will often update.

I've setup cloud functions to detect update triggers for db2 then send a message to a single device.

In my cloud function I'm reading and stashing in a collection all the unique tokens from db1.

How can I extend the cloud function to send the message to the collection of unique tokens from db1?

Should I use topics or groups for this? I don't know how big my audience can get.

I've looked at the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple) but can't quite figure out which to use.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60851881/can-fcm-topic-is-suitable-for-larger-set-of-user/60852077#60852077 for some recent, general guidance.

Comment: I see, I'll end up using topics for my use case. I'm concerned that the topics solution will throw a "429 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED ("quota exceeded") response" according to the specification [firebase topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging). What would it take for the 429 error to happen?

Comment: As the documentation you linked says: "The frequency of new subscriptions is rate-limited per project. If you send too many subscription requests in a short period of time, FCM servers will respond with a 429 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED ("quota exceeded") response. Retry with exponential backoff." It is pretty uncommon for that one to pop up on topics, unless you subscribe *a lot* of users to a topic all at once.